# How to determine the confidence interval from multiple sampling data

Tags: confidence-interval

Suppose we have 1000 students, simple random sampling 40 student for 30 times, to get their weekly expense. Now we get the mean and standard deviation of samples like

- XBar1 S1^2
- XBar2 S2^2
- … …
- XBar29    S29^2
- XBar30    S30^2

We can get the population mean expense with interval
[xBar-z*SE,xBar+z*SE]

Now we do not have the population standard deviation. I wonder what xBar and corresponding SE can we use to get the confidence interval for the population mean?

I checked several books, they just talk

- one sample condition with known population standard deviation, so we can use sigma/sqrt(n) to get SE, and use [xBar-z*SE,xBar+z*SE] to get the CI;
- one sample condition with unknow population standard deviation, so we can use the standard deviation of this sample to estimate, which means we use s/sqrt(n) to get SE, and use use [xBar-z*SE,xBar+z*SE] to get the CI;

But what if we have mulitple samples? What should be the very xBar and SE?

Intuitionly, I assume xBar should be the mean of xBar1~30, but I have no idea of the SE.

I have been hounted by this for days without good sleeping.